# OS Ticket: add coumplsory image while create a ticket

Tags: osticket

I am using OS ticket v1.14 and I want that a customer has to add/attach an image while creating a ticket.

Does anyone have idea?

Advanced thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to implement this functionality, then the OS ticket system has already given   this functionality, you can check that from their official documentation [Here](https://docs.osticket.com/en/latest/Plugins/Attachments%20on%20the%20Filesystem.html)

Also, you can watch tutorials from their [YouTube Video](https://youtu.be/7MV1WV1gF3w)

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35453604)